# A problem from Power Series of Primes

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, solution-verification

Today my math teacher explaining a problem which looks like this

If, $S=\{n\in \mathbb{N}\mid n=1 \text{ or prime numbers included in } n \text{ is either } 2 \text{ or } 3\}$ then evaluate

$${\sum_{n\in S}\frac{1}{n}}=?$$
And this infinite series sums to $3$ or you can say this sum converges to $3$.

**BUT MY QUESTION IS**

Let $R=\{n\mid \text{ as } n\to\infty \text{ prime numbers included in } n \text{ are all primes}\}$

To make it more clear this is how set $R$ looks like

$R= \{n=2^i 3^j 5^m\ldots p_k^z\ldots ; i,j,m,\ldots,z =1,2,3,\ldots \}$ where $p_k$ is the $k^{th}$ prime then

$${\sum_{n\in R}\frac{1}{n}}= \sum \sum \sum...\sum_{z=1}^\infty...\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}\frac{1}{3^j}\frac{1}{5^m}...\frac{1}{p_k^z}...$$

${\sum_{n\in R}\frac{1}{n}}$ converges or diverges?

**The definition of $R$ may look inappropriate as I'm unable to express my problem in set format to its best, but I want reader to mainly focus on this above Series expression of ${\sum_{n\in R}\frac{1}{n}}$, this is exactly what I wanted to evaluate.**

**My attempt**

$${\sum_{n\in R}\frac{1}{n}}= \sum \sum \sum...\sum_{z=1}^\infty...\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}\frac{1}{3^j}\frac{1}{5^m}...\frac{1}{p_k^z}...$$

which will be expand into product of infinite G.P. (Geometric Progression of Primes) so on simplifying we get

$${\sum_{n\in R}\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{1}{2-1}\frac{1}{3-1}\frac{1}{5-1}...\frac{1}{p_k-1}...$$

$${\sum_{n\in R}\frac{1}{n}} = \prod_{{p_t}=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{p_t-1}\right) \tag{1}$$
where $p_t$ is the $t^{th}$ prime number.

I think ${\sum_{n\in R}\frac{1}{n}}$ is convergent as its each term after $\frac{1}{2-1}$ on Right Hand Side in equation $(1)$ is $\lt 1$. Am I correct ? If not then please suggest me what can I improve or you can even write down your own answer if my method is wrong.

Comment: I would interprete the exercise as $S$ being the set of positive integers having no prime factor different from $2$ and $3$.

Comment: How should all prime numbers be included in a natural number $n$ ?

Comment: Should you mean the sum of the reciprocals of the primes : This sum is diverging !

Comment: no Sir I mean reciprocal of natural numbers containing all primes with different varying powers in i,j,m,...,z,...

Comment: A natural number can have only finite many prime factors , so $R$ is empty and the sum over $R$ therefore $0$

Comment: Probably you meant to sum over all integer powers starting at 0 (not 1) in each term. Then you would also have to take care that in each term of your infinitely nested sum, only finitely many powers can be non-zero.
In any case, what you are doing would (with some care) lead to the Euler product expansion of the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: @Peter Maybe you are right sir but and if i start stating that powers of primes can also be 0 then surely the sum will diverge but for now just for once observe the infinite summation (My attempt section) then how can we evaluate that infinite continous summation?  The main goal is to evaluate this , maybe my definition for R requires some correction but the statement for  that infinite summation is correct and I'm looking for its convergence or divergence property

Comment: @doetoe okay maybe that will give me some result I'll try if I find some lead from this . Thanks sir

Comment: @Peter Sir I edited my question, you can look at it whenever you get free

Comment: I don't see that the question has been edited.

Comment: @user2661923 sorry sir but this is the best I can do, maybe I'm lacking somewhere to express my thought

Comment: In the 2nd part of your posting, if you are not attempting (for example) to add $$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots, $$  then it might be helpful for you to explain which fractions in the harmonic series (above) that you wish to omit from your summation.

Answer (score 2):

This response reverse engineers the given answer of $(3)$.

As shown below, if you assume that the comment of Peter (immediately following the original question) is accurate, then the overall sum is in fact $(3)$.

For $0 < x < 1,$ you have that $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots  = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$.

This implies that if only the integers that are powers of $(2)$ are permitted, then you have

$$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots  = 2. \tag1 $$

Further, consider

$$1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \cdots = \frac{3}{2}. \tag2 $$

If the comment of Peter is accurate, then the problem composer's intent is that the overall sum should be computed by **cross-multiplying** the LHS of (1) with the LHS of (2).

This is clearly equivalent to $2 \times \dfrac{3}{2} = 3.$

Comment: Sir your answer is the solution of the first question which includes primes 2 or 3 , right sir ?

Comment: @AdarshKumar Yes, my answer assumes that only those fractions of the form $\dfrac{1}{n}$ should be included where $n$ is a positive integer whose prime factorization does not include any primes other than $(2)$ or $(3)$.

Comment: Okay sir for that part your solution is absolutely correct.

Comment: @AdarshKumar As far as the 2nd question in your posting goes, I am confused.  It is well known that the harmonic series $$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots $$ is a divergent series.  If I am not mistaken, your 2nd question is focusing on this series.

Comment: @user2661923 No it's not related to harmonic series as it's a divergent series, let me edit my post as the set R isn't providing accurate data of what I'm trying to ask. Sorry for the confusion